# How to loop through Arraylist <String> and added to the child node and child node added to the parent node

Tags: java, xml

I have a arraylist and need to add the list in the child node of the xml and added child node to the parent node. The below code i have written is correct ?

```
public static String generateXMLData(CouponDetails couponDetails){      
        List<String> list = couponDetails.getCOUPON();      
        String rtrnString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>"
                +"<Result_Code>"+couponDetails.getSTATUS_CODE()
                +"<Coupons>"+list+"</Coupons>"  
                +"</Result_Code>"
                ;

                return rtrnString;   
    }


@XmlRootElement
public class CouponDetails {

    private String STATUS_CODE;    
    private List<String> COUPON;

    public String getSTATUS_CODE() {        
        if(STATUS_CODE != null){
            return STATUS_CODE;
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }
    public void setSTATUS_CODE(String sTATUS_CODE) {
        STATUS_CODE = sTATUS_CODE;
    }

    public List<String> getCOUPON() {
        return COUPON;
    }
    public void setCOUPON(List<String> cOUPON) {
        COUPON = cOUPON;
    }
}
```

In the above " private List COUPON; " is the String which contain xml.

Comment: Building XML by hand is just asking for trouble. Consider using a library like [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org) (other libraries are available) to build the XML. It will take care of details like making sure the XML is well-formed and the text is escaped properly. For example, what if your coupon string contains [an XML special character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents) or the CDATA end marker (`]]>`) ?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want. In the line

```
 +"<Coupons>"+list+"</Coupons>"
```

you will call `list.toString()` so you will get something like:
[coupon1,coupon2,coupon3]

Probably, you want to cower all coupons in `<Coupon></Coupon>` tag. And you need to close `</Result_Code>` tag in correct place.

So you need to do something like:

```
+"<Coupons>"+list.stream().map((s) -> "<Coupon>" + s + "</Coupon>").collect(Collectors.joining()) +"</Coupons>"
```

This is not good, string concatenation is expensive, but probably this is the smallest changes that can fix your code.

And better solution will be with using StringBuiler, e.g.:

```
  public static String generateXMLData(CouponDetails couponDetails) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>")
        .append("<Result_Code>")
        .append(couponDetails.getSTATUS_CODE())
        .append("</Result_Code>")
        .append("<Coupons>");

    for (String coupons : couponDetails.getCOUPON()) {
      sb.append("<Coupon>")
        .append(coupons)
        .append("</Coupon>");
    }
    sb.append("</Coupons>");
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Good answer. Please close the <Result_Code> tag. :-)